# About ASIHTTPRequest resume download( File Error )

Tags: download, asihttprequest, resume

all

I use ASIHTTPRequest to download a file from the website. I try to test the attribute of suspending and resuming download. My codes just like as follow:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.delegate = self;

[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:saveTempPath];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:savePath];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
```

aha, these code can work correctly. And i can pause and resume the download.

However, if i download a png file, i find that i can't open the file correctly. The total size of the file is correct. i have compared the correct file(downloading without pausing) and the error file(downloading with pausing). i have found that the error file has some offset bytes from the pausing point (about 40 bytes).

I'm puzzled. I check the request header, and the "Range" attribute is right. And "Content-Range" of the response header is also correct. What's the problem? Please Help me.